# Send email on post/custom post type update

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-post-type

I have managed to send email on new posting but I am trying to send email when other users edit any posts, pages and custom post types. Still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code, I am using to send email, when someone add new post. I need some piece of code when someone update.

```
function wpse_19040_notify_admin_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
if ( $new_status !== 'publish' || $old_status === 'publish' )
    return;
if ( ! $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type ) )
    return;

// Recipient, in this case the administrator email
 $emailto = get_option( 'admin_email' );

// Email subject, "New {post_type_label}"
$subject = 'New ' . $post_type->labels->singular_name. " added: ";

// Email body
$message = "There has been new post. Please check below:";
$message .= 'View it: ' . get_permalink( $post->ID );

wp_mail( $emailto, $subject, $message );
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_19040_notify_admin_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Provide us with some of your code to help you find your solution.

Comment: I am not posting question to time pass, seriously looking for answer. So guys don't down vote. thanks

Comment: Check this link : http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-get-email-notification-for-post-changes-in-wordpress/

Comment: Without using plugin, my clients don't want plugin.

Comment: Then check this link : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60378/notify-admin-when-page-is-edited

Comment: wow that's great. thanks @hardiksolanki